# Magma $(\mathbb R,*)$ with a binary operation $\;a*b=a+b-2a^2b^2$

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing, associativity, magma

> Let $(\mathbb R, *)$ be a magma with a binary operation:
>   $$a*b=a+b-2a^2b^2$$ Prove
>
> $(a)$ the binary operation is commutative, but not associative,
>
> $(b)$ $0$ is a neutral element for that operation,
>
> $(c)$ $\forall x\in\langle-\frac{1}{2},+\infty\rangle$ there are two
>   inverses,
>
> $(d)$ $\forall x\in \langle-\infty,-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ there is no
>   inverse,
>
> $(e)$ for $x=\frac{1}{2}$ there exists a unique inverse.

My work:

$(a)$
$\forall a,b\in \mathbb R\;\;\;a*b=b*a$
$$a*b=a+b-2a^2b^2=b+a-2a^2b^2=b*a$$
$(b)$ $$a*b=a=a+b-2a^2b^2=a+b(1-2a^2b)\implies b(1-2a^2b)=0$$$$\implies b=0\;\;\;\; (b\; \text{independent of} \;a)$$ 
$(c)$ Asummption $\exists \;b_{1,2}\in \mathbb R$ $b_{1,2}\;=(a\;\text{inverse})$
$$2b^2a^2-a-b=0$$ $$\implies D=1+8b^3>0\implies b\in\Big\langle-\frac{1}{2},+\infty\rangle$$
$(c)\implies$ in $(d)\;:$ $$D<0\implies\forall a\in\langle-\infty,\frac{1}{2}\Big\rangle \;\nexists \;a\;\text{inverse}$$
$(c) \wedge (d)\implies$ in $(e):$
for$\;a=-\frac{1}{2}\;!\exists b$ such that $b=a$ inverse, $D=0$

What should I correct?

Comment: This appears as number 6 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388895/discuss-whether-or-not-the-following-binary-operations-are-commutative-associat), but it doesn't cover everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All in all, it would be way cleaner if $a,b$ didn't appear out of nowhere : eg for a), begin with "Let $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$".

- a) you forgot to show that $*$ is not associative. *Hint :* just take $a=1$, $b=2$ and
  $c=3$ and compute $(a*b)*c$ and $a*(b*c)$.
- b) You didn't prove that $0$ is a neutral element. What you've proven is that if there is a neutral element, then it must be $0$. The correct way to show that $0$ is a neutral element is simply to compute $a*0$ and to check that $a*0=a$.
- c) What did you prove here? I don't get it. The correct way to go is to take $x\in\langle-\frac{1}{2},+\infty\rangle$ arbitrary, then to show that the equation $x*b=0$ has two solutions.
- d) Do this : take arbitrary $x\in \langle -\infty, \,-\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ and
  show that the equation $x*b=0$ has no solution.
- e) Show that the equation $\frac{-1}{2}*b=0$ has a unique solution.

Comment: @VerkhotsevaKatya Yup, you can solve c), d) and e) at once. For $x\in \mathbb{R}$, the polynomial (in the variable $b$) $x*b = -2 x^2 b^2 + b + x$ has discriminant $\Delta_x = 1^2 - 4\cdot x \cdot -2 x^2 = 1 + 8x^3$. A study of the map $x \mapsto 1 + 8x^3$ shows that $\Delta_x>0$ for $x>\frac{-1}{2}$, $\Delta_x<0$ for $x<\frac{-1}{2}$ and lastly $\Delta_\frac{-1}{2} = 0$.